# Merge databases in Stata and create new vars based on identity and value of merged data

Tags: stata

I have two databases, DB1 and DB2, that I would like to merge, but I am having difficulties. I would like help in determining what Stata calls what I am trying to do.

DB1 has about 1000 observations and looks like:

```
   +----------+
   | date   b |
   |----------|
1. | 1      7 |
2. | 2      6 |
3. | 3      7 |
   +----------+
```

DB2 consists of 65 IDs each with about 1000 observations. It looks something like:

```
   +--------------+
   | date  id   b |
   |--------------|
1. | 1     1    4 |
2. | 2     1    4 |
3. | 3     1    5 |
4. | 1     2    9 |
5. | 2     2    8 |
6. | 3     2    7 |
7. | 1     3    1 |
8. | 2     3    2 |
9. | 3     3    1 |  
   +--------------+
```

I would like to merge DB2 with DB1 so that the ultimate database looks like:

```
   +------------------------------+
   | date   b  id1b id2b  id3b ...|
   |------------------------------|
1. | 1      7    4    9     1  ...|
2. | 2      6    4    8     2  ...|
3. | 3      7    5    7     1  ...|
   +------------------------------+
```

I have been reading about the merge command but that alone will not create my ultimate database.

Can you direct me materials that will help me with this? What do you call what I am trying to do? I feel like I need to command Stata to generate new variables.

Comment: Can't really be sure I understand which b is going where. You should give distinct values for each b in DB1 and DB2, then show what goes where in the merged dataset.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Done!

Comment: No time for a full reply, but I think you want to start with a `reshape wide b` of DB2, then `merge 1:1 date` with DB1.

Comment: Show code to make clear what your difficulties are. `dataex` (Stata 15.1 up or SSC)  is good to show data examples.

Comment: Reshape give me exactly what I was imagining. I am going to think about Nick's suggestion, what my questions are, and how I want to ask Stata those questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@William Lisowski is right. This gets you what you ask for, short of a easy `rename`. Whether it is the best structure for your analyses is unclear: most work with similar data would be easier with a further `reshape long`.

```
clear 
input date b 
1 7 
2 6 
3 7 
end 
save DB1 

clear 
input date id b 
1 1 4 
2 1 4 
3 1 5 
1 2 9 
2 2 8 
3 2 7 
1 3 1 
2 3 2 
3 3 1 
end 
reshape wide b, j(id) i(date) 
merge 1:1 date using DB1
```

Indeed, I would much more usually do something like this to get a `long` structure directly:

```
clear 
input date b 
1 7 
2 6 
3 7 
end 
rename b B 
save DB1 , replace 
clear 
input date id b 
1 1 4 
2 1 4 
3 1 5 
1 2 9 
2 2 8 
3 2 7 
1 3 1 
2 3 2 
3 3 1 
end 
merge m:1 date using DB1
```

Comment: I agree with Nick's preference for a long structure; I would need to know more about the id and b variables in DB2 to recommend stringing them out in the manner requested.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. @nickcox I will experiment with your suggested method. B is a linear combination of the ID(i)B observations, and some other stuff.  After using reshape, I have generated a var equal to the sum of all ID(i)Bs in the row.

I don't really like have so many variables, however. Maybe your method is more intuitive.

Thanks!